# Java - Map allowing null values/keys and not thread safe

Tags: java, dictionary, thread-safety

I'm looking for an implementation of the Map interface with the following requirements :

- Not thread-safe
- Not allowing null values and null keys
- In the JDK

Do you know of one ?

**Java 6**

Comment: You can use a wrapper over [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) that doesn't allow `null` key or value.

Comment: Though depending on how thorough you want to be, you'll want to make sure that it also doesn't let users set `null`s through the map views, too (i.e., `map.entrySet().next().setValue(null)`)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza how ? Can you post a detailed answer please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [**`Collections.checkedMap`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedMap%28java.util.Map,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class%29):

```
Map<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
hashMap.put(null, null); // allowed

Map<String,String> map = Collections.checkedMap(hashMap, String.class, String.class);
map.put(null, null); // results in NullPointerException
```

Now `map` is the Map that meets all of your 3 requirements I hope.

Comment: Is checkedMap bullet-proofed against `map.entrySet().next().setValue(null)` as @yshavit as stated ? However, I didn't know about checkedMap...

Comment: @Alex looks like it. Just check the javadoc.

Comment: Just a warning, this seems to have changed in Java 7 (or possibly be implementation-specific!) http://ideone.com/PrF1Ax

Comment: @Alex: You unaccepted this answer though it met your all 3 requirements, may I know why?

Comment: I have unaccepted it because you have raised a warning for Java 7. See my update in the requirements.